# Why does method signature have to perfectly match interface method

Tags: go

I began to learn Go and have trouble understanding the following:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type I interface {
    foo(interface {})
}

type S struct {}

func (s S) foo(i int) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}

func main() {
    var i I = S{}
    i.foo(2)
}
```

This fails with:

```
cannot use S literal (type S) as type I in assignment:
        S does not implement I (wrong type for foo method)
                have foo(int)
                want foo(interface {})
```

I don't understand why Go doesn't accept the `foo(int)` signature given the fact that `int` implements `interface {}`. Can anyone help with an explanation?

Comment: What would happen if the last line of the program were replaced by `i.foo("hello")`? It wouldn't be a type error, because `i.foo` accepts an argument of any type.

Comment: @PaulHankin, that's true, but what do you want to say by that?

Comment: By it I meant that if `s` satisfied the interface `I` then you'd have a well-typed program that calls `S.foo` with a string argument, even though it requires an int argument. So go's type system wouldn't be sound.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your understanding of interface isn't sound. Interface{} itself is a type. It consists of two things : underlying type and underlying value.

Golang doesn't have overloading. Golang type system matches by name and requires consistency in the types

So, when you are defining a function taking a interface type as a parameter:

```
foo(interface {})
```

This is a different function from a function taking int type:

```
foo(int)
```

So you should change the following line to

```
func (s S) foo(i interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Or better yet to this:

```
type I interface {
    foo()
}

type S struct {
    I int
}

func (s S) foo() {
    fmt.Println(s.I)
}

func main() {
    var i I = S{2}
    i.foo()
}
```

Comment: The improvement at the end is a nice touch. I see many people trying to jam fields into the methods of interfaces - rather than focusing on distilling down the methods themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The error message itself is self-explaining:

```
"S does not implement I (wrong type for foo method)"
```

so S{} which is of S type cannot be used on the RHS of type I variable assignment.

To implement I interface, type S needs to define foo function with the exact same signature.

To achieve what you wanted, you can use empty interface as input parameter for your foo function in S and do type assertion

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    type I interface {
        foo(interface {})
    }

    type S struct {}

    func (s S) foo(i interface{}) {
        if i, ok := i.(int); ok{
        fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }

    func main() {
        var i I = S{}
        i.foo(2)
        i.foo("2")
    }
```

Try [it](https://play.golang.org/p/oVtBFG4W-a-) in go playground

Comment: It's helpful that you fixed the original code as it was listed.