# Concrete type does not match interface on return type

Tags: go

I am playing around with Go and found a problem I can't get around. Suppose I have my code like this:

```
// Imagine this is an external package for querying MySQL: I run a query 
// and it gives me back a struct with a method "Result" to get the result
// as a string
// I can NOT modify this code, since it is an external package
package bar

type MySQL struct {}

func (m *MySQL) RunQuery() *MySQLResult {
    return &MySQLResult{}
}

type MySQLResult struct {}

func (r *MySQLResult) Result() string {
    return "foo"
}
```

I imported the package and started to use it:

```
// I created a little runner to help me
func run(m *bar.MySQL) string {
    return m.RunQuery().Result()
}

func main() {
    m := &bar.MySQL{}
    fmt.Println(run(m)) // Prints "foo"
}
```

I really like my helper "run", but I'd like to make it more generous: I don't expect people to always pass me a MySQL client. It could be anything that has a "RunQuery" and "Result" method. So I try to use interfaces:

```
type AnyDB interface {
    RunQuery() interface{ Result() string }
}

func run(m AnyDB) string {
    return m.RunQuery().Result()
}
```

Sadly, this doesn't compile anymore. I get this error:

```
cannot use m (type *MySQL) as type AnyDB in argument to run:
    *MySQL does not implement AnyDB (wrong type for RunQuery method)
        have RunQuery() *MySQLResult
        want RunQuery() interface { Result() string }
```

Is this not supported by Go, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The error tells you pretty clearly what the problem is--your `RunQuery` method returns the wrong type.

Comment: My question is not what the compiler is saying, but why the compiler is saying that. If you look closely, the interface I made should be describing the behaviour of the methods accurately.

Comment: Sure, but you're not returning an interface, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: This is what I am asking: the struct returned matches the interface, but Go still won't accept it. I want to know if I missed something in the implementation of my interface or it is actually something that is not supported by Go.

Comment: Found the answer: [Interfaces are types themselves, this is why it won't match the function signature. They don't behave like in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504682/why-does-method-signature-have-to-perfectly-match-interface-method)

Comment: Also you can't define methods on an interface type. As `AnyDB` is an interface, you cannot define your `run` method on that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RunQuery` should return interface, otherwise you always have to deal with strong type.

`AnyDB` is not required, I added it for connivence.

`AnyResult` should be defined in `bar` package or being imported into it.

```
type AnyDB interface {
    RunQuery() AnyResult
}

type MySQL struct{}

func (m *MySQL) RunQuery() AnyResult {
    return &MySQLResult{}
}

type AnyResult interface {
    Result() string
}

type MySQLResult struct{}

func (r *MySQLResult) Result() string {
    return "foo"
}
```

Comment: I can't change the "MySQL" library. It is an external package I got from GitHub. Sadly, they are not returning interfaces - they are returning a concrete type.

Comment: You have to live with `MySQLResult` in that case.

Comment: That's unfortunate :( Thank you for for your answer!