# Why does returning a concrete type not satisfy a Interface requiring a Interface return

Tags: go, interface

Suppose we have the following code

```go
package main

type I1 interface {
    Foo() string
}

type I2 interface {
    Bar() I1
}

type S1 struct{}

func (s *S1) Foo() string {
    return "foo"
}

type S2 struct{}

func (s *S2) Bar() *S1 {
    return &S1{}
}

func main() {
    x := &S2{}
    var i I1 = x.Bar()
    println(i.Foo())

    var y I2
    y = &S2{}
    println(y.Bar().Foo())
}
```

Now, from my viewpoint `S2` satisfies `I2`, as the return of `Bar()` satisfies `I1`, as shown in the lines above, but the compiler disagrees with me:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:28:4: cannot use S2 literal (type *S2) as type I2 in assignment:
        *S2 does not implement I2 (wrong type for Bar method)
                have Bar() *S1
                want Bar() I1
```

Yes, I understand that they are different types<sup>†</sup> , but is that not sort of the point of an interface to accept *any* type that satisfies its requirements?

Can someone give more information as to what the technical reasons may be that the satisfaction of the interface is not taken into account at this stage?

---

<sup>†</sup> [Concrete type does not match interface on return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661851/concrete-type-does-not-match-interface-on-return-type)

Comment: What a function returns is what it returns. And two things with different memory layout (e.g. I1 and *S1) are simply different things. The returned value is not subject to "if assignable than it's okay", it must match on a memory layout level. Why? Just a guess: It makes everything much easier (e.g. modifying return values in a defer), especially a interface satisfaction on Go is implicit and thus might lead to hard to prevent errors if that would be allowed.

Comment: @Volker that makes sense on some level, but I still can't reconcile the whole thing. As I understand the returned interface is a pointer anyways so we are not assigning the actual memory but rather a pointer which (afaik) is pretty much the same data layout for any type. Going further, does an interface even have a "memory layout"? It isn't it just a rule that needs to be matched and not anything that "contains" data? Also what about accepting Interfaces as args and passing in concrete types? Why can I then assign *S1 to I1 in `var i I1 = x.Bar()`?

Comment: Interface are not pointers. Interfaces have a different memory layout than a pointer. This is not specified, so it is an implementation detail and can change but they are roughly two pointers, one pointing to the actual value and one to the type (better it's method itable).

Comment: "does an interface even have a "memory layout"? It isn't it just a rule that needs to be matched and not anything that "contains" data?" That is the difference between an interface and an interface value. The abstract notion of an interface is just a collection of methods, but in Go there are variables of interface types: E.g. a `var r io.Reader` is something laying around in memory.

Comment: "Why can I then assign *S1 to I1 in var i I1 = x.Bar() ?" Technically because the language specification allows it. Informal: without that you would not be able to use interfaces: To benefit from interfaces you need to have the ability to write generic code using an interface variable and assigning a non-interface value (implementing that interface). How this works (or worked, the article is outdated but informative nevertheless): Look it up in https://research.swtch.com/interfaces

Comment: @Volker Thank you so much for the clarifications, and for taking the time to answer all the sub-questions. Also thanks for the link, I was looking for some resource like that but didn't find anything. If you feel like packaging this into an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The interface is not satisfied because the method signature does not match. The method signature specified in the interface is:
    Bar() I1
but the method signature provided is:
    Bar() *S1

you can still return a pointer to an S1 instance but you need the method signatures to match. Change the return type of the method to **I1**.

Comment: The signature obviously does not mach on a "string comparison" level, but the `Bar() I1` signature is IMO satisfied by `Bar() *S1` since `*S1` satisfies the `I1` interface. So if you re-read the question I'm asking why on a technical level this is considered "not a match".

Comment: Because it does not match. Your opinion is something you can take up with the Go team, but the compiler's opinion (as documented in the spec) is what's relevant here, and it says the signature must be identical.

Comment: @Adrian I get that my opinion is for all intents and purposes irrelevant to the world at large, and especially the compiler (and wrong in this case), but by the end of the day everyone programs based on how they think the language works (in their opinion) and the only way to really change that wrong understanding is to dig deeper. That is how I attempted to formulate my question. "That's just how it is" is not an answer to "What are the technical reasons for that's the way it is". Do you have any suggestions how the Q could be reformulated to better express that?

Comment: "Why was X designed the way it was" is, 99% of the time, a question for the designers of X, not the community at large; not only can the community not offer a definitive answer, but the question itself is opinion-based (as it is, at its core, about the opinions of the designers).